# Are any skulls/collectibles missable?

Tags: halo-infinite

I'm attempting to avoid spoilers, but I'm aware that missions cannot be replayed without starting an entirely new game.  Does this make it possible to miss any collectibles?  If so, what missions contain things that can be missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are five levels with missable collectibles, to help avoiding spoilers I will only give the mission name:

1. Warship Gbraakon
2. The Foundation
3. The Command Spire
4. Repository
5. The Silent Auditorium